# How do the searches in play store work?

Tags: android, google-play

I've just uploaded my new app in the Google Play Store. The case is the name I gave to it is not too intuitive (it's the name of the main character), so after uploading it and trying to search it in the searcher of the play store, I couldn't find it unless I type the exact name.

I know there are a lot of apps and so on, but if I have to wait until someone writes the exact name, nobody is going to see it ever.

So does anybody know how the searches work? Do they just use the name of the app? So if I write for instance: "asdf tetris bubble candy". Am I going to receive more visits?

Comment: Only Google could tell what they are exactly doing, but they won't for obvious reasons.

Comment: I am afraid that you taking the problem wrong. If a user sees your result in a search and you app is not related to the title or what he is looking for, there is very little probability he even install the app. Your best choice is to show off your work to friends, bloggers, facebook pages, events, etc to try to get the word out. There are many many blog post about the difficulty to get know on the app stores. gl

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app promotion and not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest search result to your app two ways 1 : with your package name , 2: app name Youraccountname ex: Whatsapp playaccountname